# Escaped Fragment Redirect htaccess

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, redirect

my website (`thedutchtilt.com`) employs AJAX.

Now I know that whenever Google tries to crawl a page, e.g. #!stories/component_74511, it will turn that url into `thedutchtilt.com/?_escaped_fragment_=stories/component_74511` .

My question is, how do I format a htaccess redirect so that the aforementioned site will map to the other one?

I've tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=stories/component_74511
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.thedutchtilt.com/full.html? [R=302,L]
```

but trying this just gives `http://thedutchtilt.com/?_escaped_fragment_=stories/component_74511`, which is my homepage.

I'm really confused now, and nothing seems to be working (sigh).

Kartik

**Current .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit

# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.html

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=stories/component_74511     
RewriteRule ^$ thedutchtilt.com/full.html? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Make sure your mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled. Also post your complete .htaccess here in question.

Comment: Alright, I did this, and googlebot can access the page for Plot ideas. Is this the right way to do it? Is there a better way?RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.html 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=stories/component_74511
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.thedutchtilt.com/full.html? [R=302,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing .htaccess code. Problem is your this `RedirectMatch` line:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.html
```

Comment it out and try again. `index.html` should be loaded as default using this DirectoryIndex directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Using the current Htaccess, googlebot *can* crawl my site, but, I cannot replicate this set up for my homepage. Any ideas?

Comment: `googlebot can crawl my site` has nothing to do with you .htaccess. That is controlled by robots.txt

Comment: no, not at all, as my site is built using AJAX, so in order for my site to be crawled by googlebot, this redirection must be working.

Comment: I understand AJAX part but no site will ever need `RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.html` rule as that can be easily achieved by using `DirectoryIndex index.html`

Comment: Ok, I've done that now. The strange thing is that I have identical code for all my webpages, but when I test googlebot, only the plot ideas page redirects to the basic non ajax html page, the others don't seem to work. Is it an issue of time, or have I made another mistake?

Comment: Not sure how you tested googlebot but search bots take a long time (up to few weeks) to refresh their search results.

Comment: Now nothing is working again! This is my htaccess file. When i go to any url that is supposed to forward, it just takes me back to my homepage    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteOptions inherit
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
DirectoryIndex index.html 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=stories/component_74511
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.thedutchtilt.com/full.html? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=about/mainPage
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.thedutchtilt.com/staticabout.html? [R=302,L]
 etc. I'm totally at a loss

Comment: When you say: `Now nothing is working again` what exactly is not working? Can you check Apache's error.log and tell me which URI didn't work for you?

Comment: Ok, i'll try to explain. I've set up all the redirects for ?_escaped_fragment_=, but when I try them out myself, instead of redirecting to the page I want it to go to, it just redirects back to my homepage. Because of this, Googlebot cannot index my site. I will post my htaccess in the next comment.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php


DirectoryIndex index.html 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=stories/component_74511
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.thedutchtilt.com/full.html? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=about/mainPage
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.thedutchtilt.com/staticabout.html? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=thetech/component_71401
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.thedutchtilt.com/gateway.html? [R=302,L]
 and so on for the rest of the files

Comment: Pls post your .htaccess by editing your question not in comments (very difficult to read). Anyway your .htaccess doesn't have any rule that will redirect to homepage from `?_escaped_fragment_=` URIs. Can you check access.log and error.log of Apache to see what URI is reaching to your webserver.

Comment: Sorry I will need to be offline for few hrs. Leave your comments and I will respond when I come back.

Comment: Please email me at kartikprabhu1@gmail.com this is getting out of control. I will give you my server log in details.